# Me gustaria saber si concateno correctamente en mi url con php

Tags: php, html

Quiero enviar dos datos a traves de la url, el correo y el token, pero al enviarlo, solo muestra el correo y no el token y me muestra un: "undefined index: token..." quisiera saber si el problema esta en la concatenacion. la variable token la tengo declarada.

```
<?php

    $user_email =$_POST['user_email'];
    $bytes = random_bytes(5);
    $token = bin2hex($bytes);
    include "send-mail.php";
    
    if($enviado){
        $pass = new PasswordData();
        $pass->user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
        $pass->token = $token;
        $pass->code = $code; 
        $pass->add();
        Core::alert("Codigo enviado exitosamente! Revisa tu bandeja de entrada");
        Core::redir("./?view=reset&user_email=".$_POST['user_email']."&token=".$_POST['.$token.']);
    } else{
    
        Core::alert("Oh no! Algo ha salido mal");
        Core::redir("./?view=login");
    }

?>
```

Y el enlace queda asi:

```
http://localhost/redca/foro/?view=reset&user_email=gcamilo_98@live.com&token=
```

Comment: El problema es que haces como si el token estuviese en la superglobal `$_POST` y no te está reconociendo el valor de tu variable `$token`. Debes ponerla sin más, algo así: **`Core::redir("./?view=reset&user_email=".$_POST['user_email']."&token=".$token);`**

Comment: Otra cosa, el uso indiscriminado de valores como `$_POST["user_email"]` puede ser peligroso. Espero que estés filtrando esos datos en alguna parte. Al menos en este contexto deberías someterlo a una comprobación del tipo `isset` u otra o te expones en algunos casos a un posible *`Undefined index`* al menos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado correctamente! Actualmente lo utilizo para un método de recuperación de contraseña

Comment: Pues si usas  el valor obtenido en`$_POST["user_email"]`  en una consulta de base de datos sin usar consultas preparadas te pueden inyectar código o si muestras ese valor en pantalla o lo almacenas en alguna parte. Las entradas que vienen de fuera deben ser saneadas de algún modo. A eso me refiero. Te lo advierto para que tomes medidas de seguridad oportunas según el caso.

Comment: Utilizo sentencias con mysqli, con eso será suficiente? O será mejor utilizar PDO??

Comment: Ambas son seguras, si usas correctamente las consultas preparadas, pasando los datos aparte con `bind_param` en el caso de `mysqli`.

Comment: Un punto muy importante que debo tomar en cuenta, muchas gracias por la observación, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer esto: `"&token=".$_POST['.$token.']` estás considerando que el token estaría en una entrada de la superglobal  `$_POST` cuya clave es el token que acabas de crear y por eso no te está reconociendo el valor, como puedes verificar en la URL final: `...user_email=gcamilo_98@live.com&token=`.

`$token` en una variable que no depende de la super global, así que debes ponerla directamente, algo así:

```
Core::redir("./?view=reset&user_email=".$_POST['user_email']."&token="$token);
```

Por otra parte, considera no pasar a usar datos de las superglobales sin verificarlos antes, o podrías exponerte a un *`Undefined index`* al menos.

Puedes usar *fusión de null* (PHP 7+) o en su defecto operadores ternarios, por ejemplo:

```
# Si tienes PHP < 7 cambia la línea por esto:
# $user_email =!empty($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : NULL;

$user_email =!empty($_POST['user_email']) ?? NULL;
```

Y si `$user_email` es imprescindible, agrégalo al `if`, algo así, de modo que el código no siga su curso si falta el email:

```
if($enviado && $user_email){
```

Y, dentro del `if`, ya olvídate del `$_POST` y usa la variable:

```
$pass->user_email = $user_email;
// ...
Core::redir("./?view=reset&user_email=$user_email&token=$token");
```

Si observas, esto permite escribir un código más limpio, pudiendo meter la variable dentro de las comillas dobles, sin concatenaciones.

Por último, considera aplicar filtros adecuados en los usos posteriores de datos que vienen del exterior.